# Vb.Net, SQL Server and Foxpro

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, foxpro

I want to ask about my coding with Vb.Net. I want to import data from my old Foxpro database into my SQL Server database. I have selected all columns that I need to import into my SQL Server database from Foxpro. The cause is when I try to import the data I always get error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_MsDetail'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MsDetail'.

This is my VB.NET code:

```
Private Sub btnView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnView.Click
    If txtFile.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Cannot be Empty")
    Else
        dgData.DataSource = Nothing
        path = "Q:\umum" & txtFile.Text.Trim & ".DBF"
        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=vfpoledb.1; " &
               "data source='" & "Q:\" & "'; Collating Sequence=general")

        MyCommand = New OleDbCommand("select Cd_png,cabang,subcabang,noncs,User_i,tgl_pkp,Cycle,Nama,Company,Kota,kota1,kota2,NamaKota,Telepon,Cd_post,User_ti,noncs,report3,report2,report1,report4 from [" & path & "] where cd_png ='" & txtPng.Text & "' and report3 is not null", MyConnection)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(MyCommand)

        da.Fill(DtSet, "a")
    End If

    dgData.DataSource = DtSet.Tables("a")
End Sub

 Private Sub btnExec_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExec.Click
        _thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Ribakkon))
        _thread.Start()
    End Sub

Private Function cek_ada_ga(ByRef field As String, ByRef TABLE As String, ByRef AWB As String) As Boolean
    If ConnImport.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        ConnImport.Open()
    End If
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim Nil As Boolean
    Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select " & field & " from " & TABLE & " where " & field & " = '" & AWB & "' ", ConnImport)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read Then
            Nil = False
        Else
            Nil = True
        End If
        dr.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
    End Try
    Return Nil
End Function

Private Sub Ribakkon()
        If ConnImport.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            ConnImport.Open()
        End If
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To DtSet.Tables("a").Rows.Count - 1

        If cek_ada_ga("PuNo", "MsData", Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim(DtSet.Tables("a").Rows(i).Item(1))) Then
            With DtSet.Tables("a").Rows(i)
                Dim Juliya As String
                Juliya = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim(.Item(0))
                fetch = "INSERT INTO MsData (Puno,Refno,MdName,MdCompany,MdAdd1,MdAdd2,MdAdd3,MdAdd4,MdCity,MdZip,MsDatein,MdPhone1,IdUser)"
                fetch += " values ('" & .Item(1) & "','" & .Item(1) & "','" & Regex.Replace(.Item(7).ToString, "[',]", " ") & "','" & Regex.Replace(.Item(8).ToString, "[',]", " ") & "','" & Regex.Replace(.Item(9).ToString, "[',]", " ") & "','" & Regex.Replace(.Item(10).ToString, "[',]", " ") & "'"
                fetch += ",'" & Regex.Replace(.Item(11).ToString, "[',]", " ") & "','" & Regex.Replace(.Item(12).ToString, "[',]", " ") & "','-','" & Regex.Replace(.Item(14).ToString, "[',]", " ") & "'"
                fetch += ",getdate(),'" & Regex.Replace(.Item(13).ToString, "[',]", " ") & "','JOINNES')"
            End With
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(fetch, ConnImport)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            fetch = ""
        End If

        If cek_ada_ga("PuNo", "MsDetail", Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim(DtSet.Tables("a").Rows(i).Item(1))) Then
            With DtSet.Tables("a").Rows(i)
                Dim Juliya As String
                Juliya = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim(.Item(0))
                sql += "INSERT INTO MsDetail (Puno,AWB,Periode,Code,BCode,PuDate,Noresi,FileName,Field1,Field2,MsChannel,Pudatein,IdUser)"
                sql += " values ('" & .Item(1) & "','" & .Item(3) & "','" & Mid(.Item(4), 6, 2) & Mid(.Item(4), 3, 2) & "','" & .Item(0) & "','CGK'"
                sql += ",'" & .Item(5) & "','-','" & txtPng.Text & "','" & .Item(6).ToString & "','" & .Item(2).ToString & "','FOXPRO','" & CDate(.Item(4)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + .Item(15).ToString & "','JOINNES')"
            End With
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, ConnImport)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sql = ""
        End If

    Next
    For i = 0 To DtSet.Tables("a").Rows.Count - 1
        If cek_ada_ga("AWB", "Closed", Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim(DtSet.Tables("a").Rows(i).Item(16))) Then
            With DtSet.Tables("a").Rows(i)
                Dim Juliya, STT As String
                If .Item(1).ToString.Trim = "BERHASIL" Then
                    STT = "OK"
                Else
                    STT = "RT"
                End If
                Juliya = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Trim(.Item(0))
                sql += "INSERT INTO Closed (AWB,ScStt,ScDate,ScPenerima,ScRel,ScDatein,ScNote,IdUser ) "
                sql += " values ('" & .Item(16) & "','" & STT & "','" & .Item(19) & "','" & Regex.Replace(.Item(18).ToString, "[',]", " ") & "','" & .Item(20).ToString & "'"
                sql += ",getdate(),'-','JOINNES')"
            End With
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, ConnImport)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sql = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm confused how to solve that. I need help from everybody of you guys. Big thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The data that you're inserting into the SQL table has the same data in one of the fields. In your SQL table that column is a primary key and can't have duplicate data.

Either update the data to be unique in the Foxpro database, or if that column is not supposed to be a primary key then set it not to be a primary key in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro, i explain little to you.i have two table in sql db it is MsDetail and MsData. on MsData i set PuNo to be Primary Key and on MsDetail i set  AWB to be primary and the PuNo on MsData i set to be FK on MsDetail table. the problem i got is when i insert the data, it always show error like i explain above. my main question is how can i insert the data from my foxpro into my sql though there's a same data on it? can you give me a better queries for it? Thanks before bro :)

Comment: If the field it's going into in SQL Server is a PK or there is otherwise a unique constraint on it, then you can either remove the duplicate in the VFP data, or remove the constraint in SQL Server. Coding will not get around this.